Can we implement shadcn select component without using Select.Trigger?
So, I'm trying to implement the below using shadcn select component:
I have an input box, and a button that makes an api call and gets the required result. So once the status of this api call is success, only then I want to render the select menu items. I do not want to use the <Select.Trigger> and want the select items to be rendered based on a state variable called success which is a boolean value set, if the api call succeeded or failed.
When I try to implement the above, it does not seem to be working. Even when defaultOpen is hardcoded to true not working.
Just to clarify, I don't want to hardcode the defaultOpen to true

have you tried the open properties instead? https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/select#root

could you explain a little?
